# Doing rowmean on list-columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=read.table(text="A     B      C      D
1,2   .      1,3    1,4
2,1   1,1    1,1    2,3  ", header=TRUE)

A     B      C      D
1,2   .      1,3    1,4
2,1   1,1    1,1    2,3
```

I want to do rowmeans after spliting the values, so first value before comma in all rows, then second etc
Results should be:

```
Value_1_mean         Value_2_mean
1 (3/3)              3 (9/3)
1.5 (6/4)            1.5 (6/4)
```

The parenthesis are there just to show where the means came from and are not needed.

Or

```
Value_1_mean                          Value_2_mean
First value of comma in first row     Second value of comma in first row
First value of comma in second row    Second value of comma in second row
```

I've tried some codes but I think I'm far off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in base R:

```
n <- paste0('value_',1:2,'_mean')
t(apply(df, 1,\(x) colMeans(read.table(text=x, sep=',', comment.char = '.', col.names = n))))

     value_1_mean value_2_mean
[1,]          1.0          3.0
[2,]          1.5          1.5
```

---

```
read.table(text=unlist(df), sep = ',',
            na.strings = '.', fill = TRUE, col.names = n) |>
   cbind(rn= rownames(df))|>
   aggregate(.~rn, mean, na.action = identity, na.rm = TRUE)

  rn value_1_mean value_2_mean
1  1          1.0          3.0
2  2          1.5          1.5
```

Comment: I think this is the most generalized answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table and melt to long format
df.long <- melt(setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.vars = "rn")
# split to numeric values
df.long[, c("val1", "val2") := lapply(tstrsplit(value, ","), as.numeric)]
# summarise mean by rownumber column (rn)
df.long[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(rn), .SDcols = c("val1", "val2")]
#    rn val1 val2
# 1:  1  1.0  3.0
# 2:  2  1.5  1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be more elegant approaches, but in base R you can use some regex to extract the numbers before and after the comma, then `sum` and `nchar` (for the denominator). In this context, it helps to create a helper function then pass through `apply`:

```
sumFun <- function(x){
  left <- sum(as.numeric(gsub("^(.*?),.*|\\.", "\\1", x)), na.rm = TRUE) / 
    sum(nchar(gsub("\\d+.|\\.", "", x)))
  right <- sum(as.numeric(gsub(".*?,(\\d+).*|\\.", "\\1", x)), na.rm = TRUE) / 
    sum(nchar(gsub("\\d+.|\\.", "", x)))
  
    cbind(left, right)
}

t(apply(df, 1, sumFun))


#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  1.0  3.0
# [2,]  1.5  1.5
```